# Scrolling Navbar in React App

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I am building my first React app and I would like to build a rotating / scrolling Navbar Component. A couple of websites with examples of what I'm trying to build are [Fandex](https://fandex.com/) (the better example) and also [Numberfire](http://www.numberfire.com/) (although Numberfire's doesn't scroll automatically.

Is there a Javascript library for building a moving Navbar in React?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to be a familiar with the React.Component methods. The general is `componentWillMount` - he gives you the control over the manipulation of any event on the page just after it will be loaded. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount .

For animation rotating you can you the React library - React-Transition-Group (See: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group), that gives you the full control about state changing with css effects wich you want to see on the page.

What about manual scrolling - you need to write the simple `onmousedown/onmousemove` events with some logic implementation to make it work and after bind it to the component constructor. How the events work in the React - see this manual https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

To make the full realization wich you want, stackoverflow is a not a lucky place for such huge work, sorry )